# Ways to implement a JSON RESTful service in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, json, web-services

I am trying to do a JSON Restful web service in C/C++.
I have tried Axis2/C and Staff, which work great for XML serialization/deserialization but not for JSON.

Comment: Nice question but take my advice: If you can do this web service in Java (or other framework-friendly oriented towards web service) - do it. Messing with low level stuff which C++ offers is great for learning, but it'll slow you down in most cases.

Comment: Poni has a point. Even if you "roll your own" Java service, (using, say, Jetty and Gson) you can get something simple in a few hours, I've found. There may be frameworks out there that do all of the servlet stuff for you, but nothing immediately comes to mind.

Comment: @poni and Tom. What about speed, what if I wanted to write a json framework and wanted it to be bloody fast ? Wouldn't c\c++ be a good idea ?

Comment: @gideon  yes if you can write it optimally and have lots of requests. otherwise you won't find any significant difference.

Answer (score 16):

You might want to take a look at [Casablanca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/casablanca) introduced in [Herb Sutter's blog](http://herbsutter.com/2012/04/30/c-libraries-casablanca/).

Comment: Can we use Casablanca in a production environment?

Comment: Codeplex is shutting down :(

Answer (score 9):

there are a small number of libraries that support creating rest services with c, e.g. [restinio](https://github.com/Stiffstream/restinio):

```
#include <restinio/all.hpp>
int main()
{
    restinio::run(
        restinio::on_this_thread()
        .port(8080)
        .address("localhost")
        .request_handler([](auto req) {
            return req->create_response().set_body("Hello, World!").done();
        }));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is C++ only, but you state that is a C library in your answer explicitly

Answer (score 7):

try  https://github.com/babelouest/ulfius great library to build C/C++ Restful APIs. can support all platforms: Linux, FreeBSD, Windows and others

Answer (score 3):

You could look at [ffead-cpp](http://code.google.com/p/ffead-cpp/). Apart from providing support for json and restfull web services it also includes more features. This framework may be too heavy weight for your situation though.

Answer (score 3):

For C++ web service, I am using the following stack:

- [ipkn/crow](https://github.com/ipkn/crow) C++ micro web framework
- [nlohmann/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) for json serialization/deserialization.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Oat++](https://oatpp.io/)

It has:

- URL routing with URL-parameters mapping
- Support for Swagger-UI endpoint annotations.
- Object-Mapping with JSON support.

Example endpoint:

```cpp
ENDPOINT("GET", "users/{name}", getUserByName, PATH(String, name)) {
  auto userDto = UserDto::createShared();
  userDto->name = name;
  return createDtoResponse(Status::CODE_200, userDto);
}
```

Curl:

```sh
$ curl http://localhost:8000/users/john
{"name":"john"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [webcc](https://github.com/sprinfall/webcc).

It's a lightweight C++ HTTP client and server library for embedding purpose based on Boost.Asio (1.66+).

It's quite promising and actively being developed.

It includes a lot of examples to demonstrate how to create a server and client.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [JIRA project](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2C-683?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) resolved the support of JSON in AXIS2/C .
I implemented in my project and I managed with the writer (Badgerfish convention) but still I am trying to manage with the reader.
It seems more complicated managing with the stack in the memory.

Comment: Really, it was not resolved. Resolution "Won't fix". That is because this patch: 1) for old Axis2/C-1.3, 2) very unstable and don't work at all, 3) For windows-only.

Answer (score 1):

For web service in C, you can leverage library like ulfius, civetweb:

https://github.com/babelouest/ulfius

https://github.com/civetweb/civetweb/blob/master/docs/Embedding.md

For web service in C++, you can leverage library like libhv, restbed:

https://github.com/ithewei/libhv

https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed